# With SGD, how to decide the number of steps to train?

Tags: deep-learning, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm taking the Udacity/Google's [Deep Learning course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730).

For [problem set 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/2_fullyconnected.ipynb), we are training an SGD model.

One can tune the hyper-parameters (`batch_size`, number of hidden hidden layers, number of nodes per hidden layer, etc) using techniques described here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

But how do I choose the `num_steps`? Also through hyper-parameter tuning?

Or should I look at the validation score and continue training until there is little or no improvement? If so, is there a name for this technique and does Tensorflow have this built in?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> should I look at the validation score and continue training until there is little or no improvement?

yes

[image]

> If so, is there a name for this technique

early-stopping

> does Tensorflow have this built in?

unsure